# С помощью цикла while надо вывести в консоль числа от 1 до 100. Когда делаю функцию с ней возвращает одно число 101. помогите исправить фукцию

Tags: javascript

```
 let i = 1;
  while (i <= 100) {
    
    i++
 console.log(i)
};



function Nums () {
 let i = 1;
  while (i <= 100) {
    
    i++
  } return i;
}console.log(Nums ());
```

Comment: очевидно `console.log` должен быть внутри цикла.

Answer (score 2):

Первый код у вас вполне рабочий, только console.log перенести вверх

```js
let i = 1;
while (i <= 100) {
  console.log(i)
  i++
};
```

Можно и через функцию выводить в консоль, но в этом не сильно много смысла.

```
function nums (i) {
 console.log(i)
}

let i = 1;
while (i <= 100) {
  nums(i)
  i++
};
----------------
function nums () {
    let i = 1;
    while (i <= 100) {
      console.log(i)
      i++
    };
}

nums()
```

Comment: Да, вот вопрос , как его засунуть в функцию. Чтобы была функция , выводящая числа от 1 до 100.

Comment: Функция возвращает одно значение. Можно и через функцию выводить в консоль, но в этом смысла не много. Обновил код